# log on computer of application android application running on tablet

Tags: android, debugging

I have installed some android application on google nexus 7  ( tablet) , I want see the log of those applications.

This applications are not created by me, but yet i want to see where the application crashes through the log.

I was able to do this with my iOS device, by simply connecting and opening the console in xcode. How to do this for android.

Can anyone tell, what code or what procedure is to followed. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the android tools and use adb logcat to monitor to logcat output from your device.

You will be able to see the crash stack trace, but not the code which makes it crash.

Comment: I have installed android studio , and I am not getting how to check the log on logcat through DDMS

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the page which explains this better.

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html